# Significance of $I$ being irreducible in $R/I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ and let $g(x) = x^2$

Now $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}$ while $g$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}$

Let $R = \mathbb{Z_3[x]}/(f(x))$

Let $S = \mathbb{Z_3[x]}/(g(x))$

Now, what is of interest when we compare $R$ to $S$? I have 'heard' people talk about the irreducibility of the element used to generate an ideal in a quotient ring but I don't know what the significance of it is.

Comment: $I=0$ in $R/I$. Maybe you can change that title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is of interest is simply that $R$ is a field and $S$ is not! It's easy to see the latter-since $x^2=0$ in $S$, $x$ can't be a unit. Let me show in general that for any finite field $K$ and irreducible $f$ in $K[X], K[X]/f$ is a field.

If $K$ has $q$ elements and $f$ is of degree $n$, there are $q^n$ cosets in $R=K[X]/f,$ represented by the polynomials of degree less than $n$. Let $g\neq 0$ be such a polynomial. We want to find $h$ of degree less than $n$ such that $gh= 1 \in R$. Suppose there weren't any such $h$. Then by the pigeonhole principle there must be $k\neq k' \in R$ such that $gk=gk'\in R$. But then $g(k-k')=0\in R$, which is the same as to say $f$ divides $g(k-k')$ in $K[X]$.

Here's where we use irreducibility: this implies that either $g$ or $k-k'$ is divisible by $f$. But we said $g,k,k'$ were all of degree less than $n$, so we've reached a contradiction, and there must be $h$ with $gh=1$. Then every nonzero element of $R$ is a unit, and $R$ is a field.

So, this proof gives an idea of how to construct a finite field of size $p^n$ for any prime $p$ and any $n$: just quotient $\mathbf{Z}_p[X]$ by some irreducible polynomial of degree $n$. Of course, you need to know that some such polynomial exists. There are short proofs using some field theory, or you can try a combinatorial argument that there are more degree $n$ polynomials than there are ways to multiply lower-degree polynomials to get out something of degree $n$.

Comment: Very nice explanation, just want to be clear about this - "Then by the pigeonhole principle there must be $k \neq k′ \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $gk=gk′\in \mathbb{R}$" - Ok, we've assumed there is no $h$ such that $gh = 1$, but how does that give that there must be $$k\neq k' \in R$$ such that $gk=gk'\in R$?

Comment: To be more clear: there's a function $\gamma$ from $R$ to $R$ given by $\gamma(k)= gk$. We've said $1$ is not in the image of $\gamma$. But $R$ is a finite set! That is, we're mapping the $q^n$ points of $R$ into the $q^n-1$ points of $R\setminus\{1\}$. So $\gamma$ must map two points, say $k$ and $k'$, to the same place, $gk=gk'$. Is that helpful?

Comment: Cheers, I see what's happening now.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I see how 'we use irreducibility'? What difference would it make in paragraph 3 if $f$ was reducible? We would still have that  either $g$ or $k-k'$ is divisible by $f$ and $g,k,k'$ were all of degree less than $n$ - hence we would still have a contradiction?

Comment: In fact we are not guaranteed to have $g$ or $k-k'$ divisible by $f$ when $f$ is reducible: try to follow the proof through in case $f=X^2+X$, $K$ your favorite finite field. Naturally, you should expect something to go wrong exactly where I claimed I was using irreducibility.